# Как сделать блокировку ввода повторяющегося значения?

Tags: access, vba, visual-basic, ms-access

Форма "frm_01_group".
Если для любой кафедры (поле "name_kaf") ввести уже существующее значение наименование группы (поле "name_group"), то должна происходить блокировка ввода повторяющегося значения.
Файл - [ссылка](http://transfiles.ru/czebk)

**Вопрос.**
1. Как запретить ввод повторяющегося значения?

Скрин
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не разумнее создать уникальный составной индекс, который запретит ввод таких дубликатов, и обработать ошибку дублирования?

Comment: @Akina Совсем забыл про это дело... Пробую сделать, не получается... Не могли бы вы подсказать как создать составной индекс..?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [01_group] ADD CONSTRAINT kaf_group UNIQUE (name_kaf, name_group);` Выполните (создать - запрос - режим SQL - копипаст - сохранить - открыть - согласиться на изменения), потом, если любопытно, откройте индексы в конструкторе таблицы и посмотрите, как это выглядит в визуалке.

Comment: @Akina Работает. Изменил вопрос.

Comment: Что же до подсветки введённого значения - вот оно реально надо? В табличной форме если это возможно, то "со скрыпом". Может, лучше задуматься о подчинённых формах? выбрал в основной группу, получил в подчинённой записи только для неё...